Struggling with the IBM Cloud examples for Python code when using secrets manager due to library name mismatches
I'm starting to work my way through the IBM Cloud Secrets Manager examples but hitting issues.

The examples reference secretsManager, when the library seems to use SecretsManagerV2.
It seems the get_secret function requires a value for self, but the examples don't show how to set that correctly. Is there a missing step in the examples, perhaps due to library updates?

What I want to do is obtain a secret from my instance. I have an IAM API key, I know my service URL and have that set.
I have a name for the secret, the Secret group ID, and the ID for the key, so I think I have everything I need, but I cannot work out from the examples how I should write my Python code to pull the secret value.
I followed the examples, but hit issues with library name mismatches, references in the error to needing a self value as well as the id, so I am unsure if I have missed a step, or if the examples are wrong, or if I have the wrong library.
My code is like this:
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators.iam_authenticator import IAMAuthenticator
from ibm_secrets_manager_sdk.secrets_manager_v2 import *
from icecream import ic


secrets_manager_service = SecretsManagerV2(authenticator=IAMAuthenticator(
    apikey=MY_API_KEY))


secrets_manager_service.set_service_url(
    'https://MY_PROJECT_INSTANCE.eu-gb.secrets-manager.appdomain.cloud')


response = SecretsManagerV2.get_secret(
    id='ID_OF_SECRET')

But I get an error stating:
TypeError: SecretsManagerV2.get_secret() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

I don't understand why it would need a self reference, unless I have missed a step?

Please add links to the samples and SDKs you are using.

Main source is here: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/secrets-manager/secrets-manager-v2?code=python#introduction

Sorry, new to posting in StackOverflow - didn't realise  added the comment.
Also:
Main source is here:

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/secrets-manager/secrets-manager-v2?code=python#introduction
https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/secrets-manager/secrets-manager-v2?code=python#get-secret (I had been using the create secret example but realised the correct section was just below).
Various sections of this GitHub area: https://github.com/IBM/secrets-manager-python-sdk


Your code is wrong. If you name the instance secrets_manager_service, you have to use that name....
response = secrets_manager_service.get_secret(
    id='ID_OF_SECRET')


Thanks, that makes sense, but does mean the main Cloud doc and the GitHub sample doc need some work to bring them in line or add some details to clarify that aspect.

Hi, regarding the docs: I checked https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/secrets-manager/secrets-manager-v2?code=python#introduction and it seems correct to me. Could you point out what should be corrected?

BTW: Could you mark the answer as completed and upvote it?

Apparently my reputation score is too low. I have upvoted and it says it is tracking. The problem to my mind is that the sample code shown in Cloud Secrets references SecretsManagerV2 - as soon as you connected that the reference should be what I called earlier, then it made sense. Bear in mind I was having trouble following what was in Cloud Secrets Manager as the snippets and then found the samples in GitHub so correlated that they would match. And they didn't fully.
